# confusing toString() implementation(source code) in String class

Tags: java, tostring

The overridden code of toString() in java.lang.String is as follows:

```
public String toString(){
return this;
}
```

So,printing a String reference variable should print address of reference variable(because toString() returns 'this') but not a String literal.Why am I wrong?

For Example, consider the code

```
class Sample
{
String s="dummy";
System.out.println(s);//implicit call to toString()
}
```

According to the logic in source code of toString(), address of (variable)s should be printed while output is "dummy".Why is this happening?

Comment: toString returns String object. Word `this` refers to String object.

Comment: There isn't an implicit call to `toString`. The overload of `println` which is being called is this one: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.String- Which takes a string directly, and prints each char in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there no implicit call to `toString` in this code:

```
String s="dummy";
System.out.println(s); // <== No implicit call to toString()
```

`s` is a `String`, so `System.out.println(String)` is called; no `toString` occurs.

The reason that the string's contents are output is that `System.out.println(String)` is designed to print the contents of the string.

> printing a String reference variable should print address of reference variable(because toString() returns 'this')

No. The reason you see `java.lang.Object@15db9742` or similar when calling `toString` on some objects is that the implementation of `toString` in `Object` returns a string in that form (note: it's not the address of the object). But classes like `String` override `toString` to return more useful strings, and of course in the case of `String`, the most useful string `toString` can return is the string itself.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the `System.out.println` code, it is not using `toString` but it writes a char[] which is retrieved from String:

```
public void write(String str, int off, int len) throws IOException {
    synchronized (lock) {
        char cbuf[];
        if (len <= WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE) {
            if (writeBuffer == null) {
                writeBuffer = new char[WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE];
            }
            cbuf = writeBuffer;
        } else {    // Don't permanently allocate very large buffers.
            cbuf = new char[len];
        }
        str.getChars(off, (off + len), cbuf, 0);
        write(cbuf, 0, len);
    }
}
```

The call stack of `println` before the above method (which is in `Writer`):

**PrintStream**:

```
public void println(String x) {
    synchronized (this) {
        print(x);
        newLine();
    }
}

public void print(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        s = "null";
    }
    write(s);
}

private void write(String s) {
    try {
        synchronized (this) {
            ensureOpen();
            textOut.write(s);
            textOut.flushBuffer();
            charOut.flushBuffer();
            if (autoFlush && (s.indexOf('\n') >= 0))
                out.flush();
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedIOException x) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    catch (IOException x) {
        trouble = true;
    }
}
```

**Writer**:

```
public void write(String str) throws IOException {
    write(str, 0, str.length());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

toString() is supposed to return **a** string representation of any objects (thus it exists on java.lang.Object).

When called on a string object, the string representation of that string is guess what ... the string itself; therefore toString() returns the string itself.